# Android detect where exactly the user is looking on screen in real time (Eye tracking)

Tags: android, tensorflow, opencv, computer-vision, eye-tracking

I want to detect where the user is looking on the screen and how long he sees the specific part of screen. It will be better if I'm able to detect at what widget (TextView, EditText etc..) the user is looking at the moment.

I didn't get anything perfect yet. Can we do this with any Android sensors or any other way?

Comment: this is asking for recommendations. please review [help/on-topic]